# Unresolved external symbol (LNK2001) trying to build llvm3.7 with msvc2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++, llvm, unresolved-external

I was trying to build my project with llvm3.7 (used 3.6) before using msvc2015 but now I encounter this error:

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "class llvm::FunctionPass * __cdecl llvm::createSafeStackPass(void)" (?createSafeStackPass@llvm@@YAPEAVFunctionPass@1@XZ)    myproj  C:\myproj\core.lib(Passes.obj)  1
```

How can I fix it? I build x64 on x64 OS and this the only error I get. It was fine before! I don't even use this function in my code.

Edit: to reiterate - I haven't changed anything (besides some small compatibility renames), and this is the ONLY error I get (every other function in the same header as unresolved one doesn't have this problem). Furthermore, I can "force ignore" this unresolved symbol and project builds fine, though I'm not 100% it's fully functional and won't crash somewhere due to this.

Comment: I don't think this is really a duplicate of that - this seems to be asking about a specific instance of unresolved external, rather than the general case. The fix would (probably) be to link in the appropriate library, if you know which one it was.